# how to stream a file to server and synchronously stream it to user? (usual file download imitation)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, streaming, download

I need to make a downloadable link for a file, but, for certain reasons I cannot load file directly. 
Is there any way to stream a file from its destination to remote server and immediately (at the same time) from server to user.
Thank you.

Comment: Node.js makes great use of pipes. Create a stream for the file and pipe it out to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fs.createReadStream()` and pipe that to the response object. For example:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript' });
  fs.createReadStream(__filename).pipe(res);
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: that's awesome, but I am not quite sure how to integrate it with current project structure. 
Work with data is done inside router.get() method, and, finally, all it finishes with res.render method to push data to browser page. Can I link download to some event?

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant parts of your project to show what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! you were right. I've created another router.get() method, passed necessary params and make an output like this:

res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='+query.title);
    request(link).pipe(res);
And seems that everything works fine.